# Does $\text{cov}(a_1' X, a_2' X) = 0$ imply $a_1 \cdot a_2 = 0$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pca, multivariate-analysis, covariance, eigenvalues

Let $X$ be a $p$-dimensional random vector with $p$ principal components $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_p$. By definition, a restriction put on the second principal component $y_2 = a_2'X$ is

$$
\text{cov}(y_1, y_2) = \text{cov}(a_1' X, a_2' X) = 0
$$

It is also known that $a_i$ are simply eigenvectors, so we also have

$$
\forall i \ne j, a_i \cdot a_j = 0
$$

I wonder if it's a coincidence in the context of PCA. In other words, does $\text{cov}(a_1' X, a_2' X) = 0$ imply $a_1 \cdot a_2 = 0$? I tried to prove it, but didn't get very far

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
0 &= \text{cov}(a_1' X, a_2' X) \\
&= \text{cov}(\sum_{k=1}^p a_{1,k} X_k, \sum_{m=1}^p a_{2,m} X_m) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^p a_{1,k} \sum_{m=1}^p a_{2,m} \text{cov}(X_k, X_m)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

Can I get $a_1 \cdot a_2 = 0$ from here?

Comment: Geometrically, you are asking whether two vectors remain orthogonal after an arbitrary linear transformation.  In light of this it's easy to find counterexamples in just $p=2$ dimensions. In fact, you are almost certain to find a counterexample just by randomly selecting any $2\times 2$ covariance matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a random walk model, $X_t = X_{t-1} + Z_t$ where $Z_t \overset{iid}{\sim} \text{Normal}(0,1)$. Also, assume that $X_1 = Z_1$ and has variance $1$. Take the random vector $X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)'$, it has a covariance matrix 
$$
\Sigma = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}\right].
$$
Now take $a_1 = (-1,1,0)'$ and $a_2 = (0,-1,1)$. You can see that 
$$
\text{Cov}(a_1'X, a_2'X) = \text{cov}(Z_2, Z_3) = 0
$$
but $a_1'a_2 = -1$.

Edit: just for completeness, consider the example that your mind might go to first. Consider a vector $X$ such that its covariance matrix is proportional to the identity matrix (i.e. $\sigma^2 \mathbf{I}$ with $\sigma^2 >0$). Then $\text{Cov}(a_1'X, a_2'X) = \sigma^2 a_1' a_2$ is zero if and only if $a_1' a_2 = 0$.